# How can I import and create multiple images from CSV file using Migrate Plus API?

Tags: migrations

I've done a lot of research but none of the examples seem to fit our use case.

I have a migrate plus YML file that creates images from a CSV file that will then be used on Commerce products migrate imports. This import YML works great for single images but we now need to expand it to allow for multiple images.

I've put some test images in the CSV separated by a pipe delimiter "|". But I can not get the import to properly explode or iterate through the multiple images.

The CSV file has a column called "Product Image" with a value of:

```
test.jpg|test2.jpg|test3.jpg
```

The current YML file that works with a single (non-delimited value) is below. How can we expand this YML to properly explode and create multiple images?

```
id: products_variation_photos
label: Photos associated to product variations
migration_group: my_module
migration_tags:
  - CSV
# Source.
source:
  plugin: csv      
  path: modules/custom/my_module/assets/csv/products.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - Product Image
  fields:
    Product Image: Name of the image file associated with the product.
  constants:
    file_source_uri: public://import/catalog_images
    file_dest_uri: 'public://product_images'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
process:
  filename: Product Image
  file_source:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_source_uri
        - Product Image
    # Make sure we don't have any url-unfriendly characters.
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  file_dest:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_dest_uri
        - Product Image
    # Make sure we don't have any url-unfriendly characters.
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@file_source'
      - '@file_dest'
# Dependencies.
```

Comment: Have you tried Migrate File module?

Comment: Check out this solution on Drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/2976645